# Location of the added files after the executable file is generated by pyinstaller build

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I built an executable file for my python application using pyinstaller. I added two folders (data and audio samples) by using --add-data command. The executable is working. But where can I find the two data folders I added. Aren't they put into the dist folder with executable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a data to PyInstaller it would bring your data and extract it in `one-file` mode in `temp` folder (e.g. on Windows it would be something like `C:\Users\<User>\Appdata\local\temp\_MEI60482\`) so you need to change your code to open your files from that directory. A good practice is to use this function in your code to retrieve your data. When running executable `sys._MEIPASS` would be equal to the PyInstaller temp folder.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

Then you can use it with something like `source = resource_path("audio.zip")`.

Comment: Is this _temp_ folder a real temporary one. (Does it get destroyed after executable file finish running)?

Comment: I mean if I save persistent data to a file in one of  my two folders, can I retrieve those data every time I run executable file.

Comment: This folder is a temp folder that means Pyinstaller would delete it if your app exit normally. If your app crash on uncaught exceptions the folder won't be deleted so it is not desirable and you need to handle exceptions by yourself.
You can create a temp folder by yourself and put your data inside it, standard programs usually use `appdata/roaming` for their data files. Then it is by yourself if you want to delete it or not.